# $q$-analog generalization for limits not going to 1

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions, q-analogs

I have been recently introduced to $q$-analogs, and find them quite interesting, specially for their connections going from Ramanujan expressions to very broad aplicable subjects.

As I humbly understand them they are parametrized families that give us regular combinatorial expressions when $q \rightarrow 1$, but that evaluated at other $q$ ( I think only integers) gave us counting formulas too, They also happen to interact very nicely between them. (factorials, binommials properties etc)

Then has anyone studied parametrized families that approach the regular expression when $ q \rightarrow 2$? Or when $q \rightarrow k$ for $k\in \mathbf{Z}$? Is $k=1$ the only interesting case?

Also Trying to not only play with integers, what if we modify exponential generating functions replacing $e$ with $e^q$, this would give us the regular result as $q \rightarrow 1$ again, but maybe give us some generalizations where $q$ is a parameter.
Have this being studied? Exponential Generating functions for $q$ analogs too?

I know this is very open question but I just would like to speak a little about this with someone in this pandemic contrived academia, some expressions or just references could do.

Comment: This curiosity all started  by investigating the expression $$ \frac{e^6 A_5(e^{-1})}{e^6(1-e^{-1})^{5+1}}  \approx 5!$$ Where $A_n$ are the Eulerian polynomials, sadly this is only the case for $1<n<16$
but it sparkled my interest in combinatorial and analysis subjects, including $q$-analogs. Just to add another very crazy idea, What if maybe we introduced $\varphi$ or some other numbers to generating functions... ?? the family $e^q$ really would be quite natural compared to other trascendental numbers, but it's not like $\varphi$ doesn't have also connection with combinatorics...

Comment: Finite fields exist for prime powers $q$. For corresponding $q$-identities, formulas etc. you don't need to take a limit since you can just *plug values in directly*. Products and quotients of powers of $q$ and $q$-integers, and summations of these things, only have issues with plugging in $q=1$. Also see the "field with one element" or, for examples where we plug roots of unity in for $q$, "cyclic sieving phenomenon."